# How to create a type table of a the type representing the columns of a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table a. I would like to create a table type of a%rowtype

```
create table a ( a1 integer);
CREATE TYPE t_a iS TABLE of a%ROWTYPE;
```

> schema-level type has illegal reference to user.a

I've tried with

```
create table user.a ( a1 integer);
CREATE TYPE user.t_a iS TABLE of a%ROWTYPE;
```

> same problem

But these 2 alternative solutions work

```
create package p_a
as
type t_a iS TABLE of a%ROWTYPE;
end;

create type o_a is object  (a1 integer);
CREATE TYPE t_oa iS TABLE of o_a;
```

Is there a way to make the 2 first lines of code work?

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d173cb899bfab90859268ba8ea004b2e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the other way round and create a object-derived table (rather than trying to create a table-derived object).

```sql
CREATE TYPE a_obj IS OBJECT (
  a1 INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE a OF a_obj;

CREATE TYPE t_a IS TABLE OF a_obj;
```

---

> Is there a way to make the 2 first lines of code work?

No, `%ROWTYPE` is PL/SQL syntax and it will not work in the SQL scope.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a8056c3302fa0e8a99382dbea56ca803)*